# SQL INNER JOIN update NOT duplicating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have an update query that has an inner join. I expect this query to return two columns because of the join, but it seems that the QUERY is taking only the first row and using that to update the data while ignoring the rest.

Here is my update command

```
UPDATE [mamd]
    SET [Brand_EL] = IIF(CHARINDEX('ELECT', UPPER([mml].[Brand_Desc])) > 0, 'YES', [Brand_EL])
    FROM [mamd] [m]
         INNER JOIN [ior] [ir] ON [ir].[CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID] = [m].[CustomerId] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
         INNER JOIN [maslist] [mml] ON [mml].[Model] = [ir].[MODEL] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

If I do a select like this

```
SELECT [ir].[CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID], IIF(CHARINDEX('ELECT', UPPER([mml].[Brand_Desc])) > 0, 'YES', [Brand_EL])
    FROM [mamd] [m]
         INNER JOIN [ior] [ir] ON [ir].[CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID] = [m].[CustomerId] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
         INNER JOIN [maslist] [mml] ON [mml].[Model] = [ir].[MODEL] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

I get the following data returned

```
CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID | Brand_EL
-------------------+----------
980872             | NO 
980872             | YES
```

The reason I think it's only taking one record is because

1. The value NEVER changes to "YES"
2. When I run the update command it says only 1 row updated even though it should have gone through two

One thing that might be contributing to the problem is that `[mamd]` does NOT contain multiple records for that same user; It's a unique field. Since it's a unique field and therefore only has one row, does that mean that it will run that join only once? If that's the case, is there a better way I can do this without nested selects to generate the results?

### UPDATE

Hey Everyone,

Just as an update, I took Gordons Advice and use aggregation. In this example that I have, I only cared if the value was "YES' because I only need to know if the customer bought a specific product. So what I ended up doing was grouping by the Customer ID and using the MAX function. If the customer bought a product, "YES" would bubble up to the top. If he didn't it would stay as NO or NULL. In that event, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is correct and documented, although not in a very clear way:

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria
>   for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are
>   undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not
>   specified in such a way that only one value is available for each
>   column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is
>   not deterministic. For example, in the UPDATE statement in the
>   following script, both rows in Table1 meet the qualifications of the
>   FROM clause in the UPDATE statement; but it is undefined which row
>   from Table1 is used to update the row in Table2.

What this is trying to say is that a row is only updated once by the `update`.  Which value gets used is indeterminate.  So, if you need to decide how you want to handle the multiple matches.

Comment: Thanks, so it's what I thought. Would you have any recommendations? The only two solutions I can think of is, 1. loop and have a more restrictive condition so that it returns only one row, 2. Do lots of nested queries like SET [Brand_ELX] = (SELECT 'yes' FROM ....). I think both solutions are awful because there are huge performance issues, but is this basically the only way? Please note that Brand_ELX is one of maybe 15 columns that are all built in very similar ways which is why I really don't like option 2.

Comment: @JohnathanKong . . . If you want both updates, then some form of aggregation is used.  It is not clear to me from your query what the logic should be.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The simplified logic is, I have a customer record in the [mamd] table. If that customer buys a product, I will keep checking all their purchases in the [ior] table until I see they purchased an ELECT product. Once I find a record that says this customer purchased the product, I set the column to 'YES'. Sorry, that's really simplified but hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnathanKong . . . You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.